# How to add an image in jquery function generated text

Tags: jquery

I have a function that greets the user {GOOD MORNING, GOOD AFTERNOON, GOOD EVENING AND GOOD NIGHT} based on system time using Jquery.

I am trying to insert an image in the various messages (sun,moon...)

```
function updateWeatherLocationAndTime() {
//get the user system time
var timeInHours = new Date().getHours();
//set the greeting based on time
var greets = "Night";
if (timeInHours >= 6 && timeInHours < 12)
  greets = "Morning";
else if (timeInHours >= 12 && timeInHours < 17)
  greets = "Afternoon";
else if (timeInHours >= 17 && timeInHours < 21)
  greets = "Evening";
//update the greeting
updateElement('#time-of-day', greets);
```

this is an example of what I would like to do
 http://prnt.sc/f8978t

this is a the current code

http://jsfiddle.net/c5hcbdke/

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either put the `<img>` tag directly in the `greets` string, or you can update an existing  tag.

---

First example:

`greets = 'Night <img src="moon.jpg" alt="" />';`

---

Second example:

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <span class="greeting">
        Good <span id="time-of-day">Morning</span> <img src="" alt="" id="time-of-day-img" />
  </span>
</body>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function updateWeatherLocationAndTime() {
//get the user system time
var timeInHours = new Date().getHours();
//set the greeting based on time
var greets = "Night";
var image = "moon.jpg";
if (timeInHours >= 6 && timeInHours < 12) {
  greets = "Morning";
  image = "sunrise.jpg";
}
else if (timeInHours >= 12 && timeInHours < 17) {
  greets = "Afternoon";
  image = "sun.jpg";
}
else if (timeInHours >= 17 && timeInHours < 21) {
  greets = "Evening";
  image = "sunset.jpg";
}
//update the greeting
updateElement('#time-of-day', greets);
$('#time-of-day-img').attr("src", image);
```

Comment: the second example worked perfectly, the first one was only displaying it as is Night <img src="moon.jpg" alt="" />

thank you!

Comment: also, curly braces  after the IF contidions were need otherwise it wouldnt work...
   if (timeInHours >= 6 && timeInHours < 12){
      image = "morning.png";
      greets = "Morning";
      
    }

Comment: @Gad My bad about the curly braces. I was going to "explain" the second example, but then decided to give a code example just before I posted the answer, and I didn't put as much thought into it as I should have.  I've updated the answer to correct that.

Comment: As for the first example outputting the parsed HTML, my assumption would be that it's due to something the `updateElement()` function is doing. If you absolutely needed to use the first method, you would just need to change the use of the updateElement() to `$('#time-of-day').html(greets);`